# "Shutdown" button on desktop?

Tags: shutdown

I just uninstalled OpenSuSE 12.2 from my Sony Vaio laptop because the OS offered no "Shutdown" button on the desktop. I had to log out, and then just hold the laptop's Power button down 'til the laptop shut off.

Does Ubuntu 12.x offer such a button or similar?

Comment: It does offer a shutdown option in the menu and you can make a desktop shortcut to shutdown your computer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[image]

I'm pretty sure SuSE also has shutdown option somewhere.

Comment: I just played with OpenSuSE 12.2 on my desktop.  It had shutdown options in both KDE and Gnome...

Comment: It is a common sense issue. An OS must must have a shutdown option in menu.